# How do I compute the number of times a character appears in a character array in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to determine the number of times a character appears in a character array, excluding the time it appears at the last position.

How would I do this?

Comment: Convert your string using `cellstr`, then use the duplicate linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Matlab` computing environment, [all variables are arrays, and strings are of type char (character arrays)](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html). So your Character Array is actually a string (Or in reality the other way around). Which means you can apply string methods on it to achieve your results. To find total count of occurrence of a character except on last place in a String/Character Array named `yourStringVar` you can do this:

```
YourSubString = yourStringVar(1:end-1)
//Now you have substring of main string in variable named YourSubString without the last character because you wanted to ignore it

numberOfOccurrence = length(find(YourSubString=='Character you want to count'))
```

It has been pointed out by Ray that `length(find())` is not a good approach due to various reasons. Alternatively you could do:

```
numberOfOccurrence = nnz(YourSubString == 'Character you want to count')
```

`numberOfOccurrence` will give you your desired result.

Comment: `length(find(...))` is very bad - inefficient, slightly obfuscated, and perhaps inelegant.  Use `nnz` instead: `nnz(YourSubString == 'character')`.

Comment: @rayryeng I am sorry I am only a Freshman. I will edit the answer and add your suggestion to it.

Comment: No problem at all :) TBH, I would have used `length(find(...))` many years ago when I first started.  Just giving a bit of advice as I now know better.  BTW, I see you are a new member.  Welcome!

Comment: Thanks Ray :)  Looking forward to contribute and expand my knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, it really helps.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is map each character into a unique integer ID, then determine the count of each character through [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html).  Use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to complete the first step.  The first output of `unique` will give you a list of all possible unique characters in your string.  If you want to exclude the last time each character occurs in the string, just subtract 1 from the total count.  Assuming `S` is your character array:

```
%// Get all unique characters and assign them to a unique ID
[unq,~,id] = unique(S); 

%// Count up how many times we see each character and subtract by 1
counts = histcounts(id) - 1;

%// Show table of occurrences with characters
T = table(cellstr(unq(:)), counts.', 'VariableNames', {'Character', 'Counts'});
```

The last piece of code displays everything in a nice table.  We ensure that the unique characters are placed as individual cells in a cell array.

Example:

```
>> S = 'ABCDABABCDEFFGACEG';
```

Running the above code, we get:

```
>> T

T = 

    Character    Counts
    _________    ______

    'A'          3     
    'B'          2     
    'C'          2     
    'D'          1     
    'E'          1     
    'F'          1     
    'G'          1
```